# semantics of whether social links go in a <nav> element or not

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm still pretty new to html5 and I'm curious about the semantics of whether or not I should put social links (*facebook*, *twitter*, etc.) in either a ***<nav>***, ***<menu>***, or ***<div>*** element.

I am trying to learn the best practices along with the language so I dont develop bad habits early on. I think I understand that ***<nav>*** is meant to be used for main site related links only. However I thought I'd try to get some clarity before assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a specifically element to place the social media anchors, I would say the most common and better one is to place it inside a `div` element, but it's a really open question with a lot of possible answers.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty much just curious if there was a common practice that is suggested and less frowned upon that others.

Comment: if you don't want to develop bad habits early on, avoid divisitis. a list of links should go in a list. ul or ol. wrapped in a div if necessary, but certainly not always needed.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there doesn't seem to be any standard for what to put social links or social share buttons in, so it's really up to you, but it is possible to rule some options out.

**NAV element definition:**
"The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links. Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element only sections that consist of major navigation blocks are appropriate for the nav element. In particular, it is common for footers to have a list of links to various key parts of a site, but the footer element is more appropriate in such cases, and no nav element is necessary for those links."

Based on this definition you could potential rule out the NAV tag, because the social links are not linking to other sections of the page or website and they are not considered "major navigation blocks" on a page.

**MENU element definition:** "The menu element represents a group of commands that a user can perform or activate. This includes both list menus, which might appear across the top of a screen, as well as context menus, such as those that might appear underneath a button after it has been clicked."

Based on this definition you could also rule out the MENU tag, because it is semantically meant for app functionality, or rather javascript events, to control the page/app. It isn't meant to be used for links.

So this leaves you with the DIV tag, but I would also argue that the UL tag could work just as well, if not better. Placing your social media links in the list would give slightly more context to a screen reader, because they would know they are entering a list of items. When a screen reader reaches a DIV tag they can't determine any information about it, unless you supply an aria-label attribute to the markup.

**TL;DR;** My recommendation would be to use a UL element to hold your social links/buttons.

Answer (score 3):

If the social links are contextual to the website/author, they're essentially contact information; so you can use `<address>` for them.

[Address--MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address)

[Address--Standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-address-element)

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I found that it is better to use the  tag. It may be wrapped in  tag also. Check the following link https://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/BgQqrQ?editors=1000 to see some semantic page layout.

```
<aside>

  <section class="share">
    <h2>Share</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <!-- Not sure <section> adds value here -->
  <!-- Leaving as it does not add SR noise -->
  <section class="recommended">
    <h2>Recommended</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <!-- Removed unnecessary <article> -->
        <!-- The content is in a list item, -->
        <!-- in a list, under a heading, in a region -->
        <!-- This is overkill -->
        <!-- Removed unnecessary <h3> -->
        <!-- See preceding reasons -->
        <!-- Left in a <p> so no need to rely on CSS -->
        <!-- that would still cause SRs to run it together -->
        <p><a href="#">Related article</a></p>
        <p>Article description</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- Removed unnecessary <article> -->
        <!-- The content is in a list item, -->
        <!-- in a list, under a heading, in a region -->
        <!-- This is overkill -->
        <!-- Removed unnecessary <h3> -->
        <!-- See preceding reasons -->
        <!-- Left in a <p> so no need to rely on CSS -->
        <!-- that would still cause SRs to run it together -->
        <p><a href="#">Related article</a></p>
        <p>Article description</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

</aside>
```